# How can I use Artifact Deployer to copy from the archived artifacts, instead of the workspace?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

We've been using Jenkins for a while, now, and have used the ArtifactDeployer plugin to copy build artifacts out of the working directory to our artifact repository fileshares.

I'm working on a new deployment promotion job, that needs to obtain the artifacts of a given build, and I thought I might use the Copy Artifact plugin. But that expects that the artifacts be saved using Jenkin's artifact archive feature, which we've not been using.

There are some nice features, in the Copy Artifact plugin - we can configure it to specify the upstream build that triggered the job, rather than having to pass a specific build number as a parameter. But to use it, we'd need to configure archive.

But we still need to copy artifacts to our artifact repository fileshares, which means we have to specify the files we want to archive twice - once in the archive config and once in the ArtifactDeployer config.

Unless we can configure the ArtifactDeployer plugin to copy the contents of the archive directory.

Is this possible?

What would be the path?